# RequestVerificationToken passed in headers in ajax call doesn't appear in HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, download

For preventing cross site request forgery, I'm passing the following Request Verification Token in filedownload call along with data. 
But I'm seeing in HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers, this token doesnot exist. [I'm using jquery.fileDownload.js for this]

```
$.fileDownload("Account/downloadFile", {
httpMethod: 'POST',
headers: {
   "__RequestVerificationToken":  $(':input:hidden[name*="RequestVerificationToken"]').val() 
},
successCallback: function () {

},
failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {

},
prepareCallback: function () {
    //logger.log(" File Downloaded ", "", "", "success");
}
```

});

What I can see in my validateAntiforgeryToken method is HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"] = null

Any idea ? Please help.

Comment: `__RequestVerificationToken` is POSTed in the body of the request and not in the headers. Do you see it in `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["__RequestVerificationToken"]`?

Comment: I can't change my serverside code. Actually I need to pass it in headers. But if I pass it in headers, it is null

Comment: In HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["__RequestVerificationToken"] it is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the token to the headers instead use the headers property:

```
$.fileDownload("Account/downloadFile", {
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    headers: {
        '__RequestVerificationToken': $(':input:hidden[name*="RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    }
```

Comment: I'm passing in the same way, but it is not available in HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]

Rather it is available in HttpContext.Current.Request["__RequestVerificationToken"]

Comment: Your code above isn't passing it in the headers though? You need to use headers for the token for it to work.

Comment: After I followed your answer, I'm passing it in headers